# javascript map function for objects multi level

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dynamodb-queries

How can I loop through all the entries in an array using JavaScript? , javascript map function for objects multi level

**Example**

```
const  myObject = [
  {
    'name' : {'s': 'name1'},
    'surname' : {'s': 'surname1'},
    'tel' : {'n': 2223456789}
  },
  {
    'name' : {'s': 'name2'},
    'surname' : {'s': 'surname2'},
    'tel' : {'n': 1234567890}
  }
]
```

**Result**

```
const newObject = [
  {
  'name' :'name1',
  'surname' : 'surname1',
  'tel' : 2223456789
  },
  {
  'name' : 'name2',
  'surname' : 'surname2',
  'tel' :  1234567890
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
const myObject = [
    {
        'name': { 's': 'name1' },
        'surname': { 's': 'surname1' },
        'tel': { 'n': 2223456789 }
    },
    {
        'name': { 's': 'name2' },
        'surname': { 's': 'surname2' },
        'tel': { 'n': 1234567890 }
    }
]

const newObj = myObject.map(mo => {
    const o = {};
    for (const k in mo) {
        o[k] = mo[k][Object.keys(mo[k])[0]];
    }
    return o;
})

console.log(newObj);
```